# Reading and removing Exchange from SEDA queue in Camel

Tags: spring, queue, apache-camel

About SEDA component in Camel, anybody knows if a router removes the Exchange object from the queue when routing it? My router is working properly, but I'm afraid it keeps the Exchange objects in the queue, so my queue will be continuously growing...

This is my router:

```
  public class MyRouter extends RouteBuilder {

      @Override
      public void configure() {
        from("seda:input")
          .choice()
          .when(someValue)
          .to("bean:someBean?method=whatever")
          .when(anotherValue)
          .to("bean:anotherBean?method=whatever");
      }
}
```

If not, does anybody know how to remove the Exchange object from the queue once it has been routed or processed (I am routing the messages to some beans in my application, and they are working correctly, the only problem is in the queue).

Another question is, what happens if my input Exchange does not match any of the choice conditions? Is it kept in the queue as well?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Edited: after reading Claus' answer, I have added the end() method to the router.  But my problem persists, at least when testing the seda and the router together. I put some messages in the queue, mocking the endpoints (which are receiving the messages), but the queue is getting full every time I execute the test. Maybe I am missing something. This is my test:

```
@Test
  public void test() throws Exception {
    setAdviceConditions(); //This method sets the advices for mocking the endpoints

    Message message = createMessage("text", "text", "text"); //Body for the Exchange
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      template.sendBody("seda:aaa?size=10", message);
    }

    template.sendBody("seda:aaa?size=10", message); //java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue full
  }
```

Thanks!!

Edited again: after checking my router, I realised of the problem, I was writing to a different endpoint than the one the router was reading from (facepalm)

Thank you Claus for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

1)

Yes when a Exchange is routed from a SEDA queue its removed immediately. The code uses poll() to poll and take the top message from the SEDA queue.

SEDA is in-memory based so yes the Exchanges is stored on the SEDA queue in-memory. You can configure a queue size so the queue can only hold X messages. See the SEDA docs at: http://camel.apache.org/seda

There is also JMX operations where you can purge the queue (eg empty the queue) which you can use from a management console.

2)

When the choice has no predicates that matches, then nothing happens. You can have an otherwise to do some logic in these cases if you want.

Also mind that you can continue route after the choice, eg

```
@Override
  public void configure() {
    from("seda:input")
      .choice()
        .when(someValue)
          .to("bean:someBean?method=whatever")
        .when(anotherValue)
          .to("bean:anotherBean?method=whatever")
      .end()
      .to("bean:allGoesHere");
  }
```

eg in the example above, we have end() to indicate where the choice ends. So after that all the messages goes there (also the ones that didnt match any predicates)